# Need a query to find the records that have different values for same id in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am really confused here.

I need to find those `CustTreeNodeId`'s which have (`PreferenceID` = 55 and `OverrideValue` = 1 ), (`PreferenceID` = 56 and `OverrideValue` = 1),(`PreferenceID` = 58 and `OverrideValue is not null`).

The record should have all three `PreferenceID` and should statisfy all three conditions mentioned above.

Example - See `CustTreeNodeID` = `76853551-7ACD-48E1-BEFF-0000498A144C` in Screenshot.

[image: This is my table]

Comment: Show what you tried to do

Answer (score 1):

these will gives you the CustTreeNodePreferenceOverrideID that you need

```
SELECT CustTreeNodePreferenceOverrideID
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  ( condition 1 )
OR     ( condition 2 )
OR     ( condition 3 )
GROUP BY CustTreeNodePreferenceOverrideID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: This will fail when there are say two records which satisfy condition 1 and one record for condition 2 but no records for condition for same CustTreeNodeId

Answer (score 1):

you can use `EXISTS` clause in this case

```
select 
    CustTreeNodeId 
from yourtable t1
where 
    exists
        ( 
            select  1 from yourtable t2 
            where t2.CustTreeNodeId =t1.CustTreeNodeId  
            and 
            (t2.PreferenceID = 55 and t2.OverrideValue = 1 )
        )
    and exists
        ( 
            select  1 from yourtable t3 
            where t3.CustTreeNodeId =t1.CustTreeNodeId  
            and 
            (t3.PreferenceID = 56 and t3.OverrideValue = 1)
        )
    and exists
        (
            select  1 from yourtable t4 
            where t4.CustTreeNodeId =t1.CustTreeNodeId  
            and
            (t4.PreferenceID = 58 and t4.OverrideValue is not null)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustTreeNodeID 
FROM myTable 
WHERE   (PreferenceID = 55 and OverrideValue = 1 ) 
OR  (PreferenceID = 56 and OverrideValue = 1)
OR (PreferenceID = 58 and OverrideValue is not null)
GROUP BY CustTreeNodeID 
HAVING COUNT(PreferenceID)=3
```

Comment: Code may be answer, but it is better to add some explanation

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT CustTreeID 
FROM   yourtable t
WHERE  (t.PreferenceID IN (55,56) AND t.OverrideValue=1)
OR (t.PreferencedID =58 AND t.OverrideValue IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY CustTreeID
HAVING COUNT(t.OverrideValue) = 3
```